# EmberJS set active class for dynamic linkTo on menu when direct accessed

Tags: json, ember.js, dynamic, hyperlink

i've been trying this since last week, to make the active class work on those dynamic links:

```
<li>{{#linkTo tag 'bw'}}Black and White{{/linkTo}}</li>
<li>{{#linkTo tag 'instax'}}Instax{{/linkTo}}</li>
<li>{{#linkTo tag 'digital'}}Digital{{/linkTo}}</li>
```

I put a code running here: http://jsbin.com/opuzop/1/edit so if you feel ok to help me with that would be great :D it's my photo portfolio as well.

Also, if I try to upload to the newer version of Ember, some stuff stop to work, like the JS I created on

```
App.GeneralView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        if(this.$() !== undefined){...
```

It was created to load after the view render, so I do a image resize and a body resize too, and set everything horizontal, but with the newer version it only work when accessed directly.

Also, sometimes it don't get the JSON from Tumblr and stop working.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I think it has to do with the serialization of your object, try adding something like this in your "App.TagRoute" route:

```
serialize: function(param) {
  return {tag: param.tag}
}
```

Comment: for the problem you have with the didInsertElement function when you update to the latest ember version, take a look at this page http://eviltrout.com/2013/06/09/ember-rc5-upgrade-notes.html in the "Initializing State in didInsertElement" section

Comment: I see, well, the: `serialize`only worked this way: `serialize: function(param){return {tag: param} }` with the `param.tag` i got undefined, also still not setting activate class :((